# Can @Retry and @Recover be used when using error handler in RestTemplate?

Tags: java, error-handling, resttemplate, spring-retry

I am using Rest Template to call a rest API. To handle the exceptions, I am using a custom ErrorHandler.

I have also used @Retry and @Recover. When at first there is a ConnectException from the URL, the call should be made on the second URL. However after 3 attempts, the ExhaustedRetry 'could not find Recover method' exception is being thrown, even though I have defined a recover method.

Is it because I am using an ErroHandler and not explicitly throwing the exception?

Below is a skeleton of my code -

```
@Component
public class TestCall {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private boolean flag = false;

@Retryable(value = {ConnectException.class}, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 96, maxDelay = 158, random = true))
public void callAPI() {
    
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestErrorHandler());

    if (!flag) {
        // calling first URL
        flag = !flag;
        restTemplate.exchange(url1, HttpMethod.POST, body, Response.class);
    } else {
        // retrying with 2nd url if 1st url fails with ConnectException
        flag = !flag;
        restTemplate.exchange(url2, HttpMethod.POST, body, Response.class);
    }
    
}

@Recover
public void recover(ConnectException exception) {
    System.out.println("In recover method");
}}
```

The error handler -

```
public class RestErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    //logging the error here
}
}
```

After retrying 3 times, if the exception is thrown the 4th team, the recover method is not being called.

Comment: The error handler has to throw an exception for retries to be invoked so it's not clear how you are getting 3 retries. See the `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`. Also, your `flag` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Yes I was confused about that too. I am getting three retries, but its just not going to the Recover method after that. Thanks, I will try the Default one too. Thanks for the tip about the flag. I have taken care of that, haven't posted the whole code here. @Gary Russel